# Keyboard is not showing on single click

Tags: android, keyboard

i am trying to show keyboard onclick 
but it is not showing automatically (keyboard is in hidden state in manifest)
working but on double click...
here is the source.

```
        search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            search_friends.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            //my_friends.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            search_friends.requestFocus();
            if(search_friends.hasFocus())
            {
                getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
            }
        }
    });
```

i want this on single click...

Answer (score 1):

this is my method, I made it for an Util class, I use it in every project and it works:

```
/**
     * For hide ed == null <br/>
     * For show ed !=null
     * 
     * @param context
     *            Activity
     * @param ed
     *            EditText
     */
    public static void hideOrShowSoftKeyboard(Activity context, EditText ed) {
        try {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            if (ed != null) {
                inputManager.showSoftInput(ed, 0);
            } else {

                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(context.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            }

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            LogService.log(TAG, "NullPointerException");
        }
    }
```

// in your implementation

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         search_friends.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
         //for showing the keyboard
         AppNameUtils.hideOrShowSoftKeyboard(this,search_friends);
       }
```

Comment: but for my case what should be it it...?